# настройка metallb нет маршрута до узла

Tags: kubernetes

Ubuntu ver 20.

Пробую настроить  metallb в minikube
и получаю

```
нет маршрута до узла
```

в minikube добавляю metallb

minikube ip

```
192.168.49.2
```

Вот файл metallb-config.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.49.101-192.168.49.111
```

Применяю его и проверяю, командой

```
kubectl describe configmaps -n metallb-system
```

файл nginx-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment 
metadata: 
  name: nginx-deployment 
spec: 
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      app: nginx 
  replicas: 3
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: nginx 
    spec: 
      containers: 
      - name: nginx 
        image: nginx:latest 
        ports: 
        - containerPort: 80
```

и сервис nginx-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Service 
metadata: 
  name: nginx 
spec: 
  type: LoadBalancer 
  selector: 
    app: nginx 
  ports: 
  - port: 80 
    name: http
```

Запускаю все это, проверяю

```
kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>           443/TCP        14m
nginx        LoadBalancer   10.101.36.165   192.168.49.101   80:31744/TCP   10m
```

и захожу по адресу:

```
curl http://192.168.49.101
```

в результате получаю

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.49.101 port 80: Нет маршрута до узла
```

Comment: а на какой системе и как вы установили minikube (vbox, hyperkit и т.д.)?

Comment: ос добавил в сообщение, а ставил по этой инструкции
https://kubernetes.io/ru/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/

Comment: а запускаю миникуб на докере с virtualbox у меня так и не получилось